How to use an array in a subsequent query (Oracle SQL 19c)
I'm failing to properly structure this script to output the results of a join based on an array of numbers, I've went through some failed attempts and I'm getting a bit lost!
I start off with a single entitykey, I join this key to another table which produces several more keys, these keys are joined to another table which produces a new key for each previous key, using this final set of keys I must join to a final table where I will receive a result for each key.
I have a script working which fetches the first set of keys and assigns them to an array, and I have a simple join that works by manually inputting each key and running the script each time per key.
I'm trying to write the script so that the I generate an array, and loop a query for each number in the array.
Here is the query that generates the array:
`CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE varray IS TABLE OF number;

DECLARE
      releasableentitykey  varray := varray();
BEGIN
      FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM masterbatchrecordreleasesignat  
              INNER JOIN masterbatchrecord ON masterbatchrecordreleasesignat.releasableentitykey = masterbatchrecord.entitykey
              WHERE masterbatchrecord.entitykey='7884867406')
            LOOP
        releasableentitykey.extend;
        releasableentitykey(releasableentitykey.count) := i.Releasesignaturecollectionenti;
            END LOOP;
 END;`

This works and produces the list of keys I expect.
The second query which is not working:
SELECT * FROM signature  
INNER JOIN releasesignature ON signature.entitykey = releasesignature.signatureentitykey
INNER JOIN masterbatchrecordreleasesignat ON releasesignature.entitykey = masterbatchrecordreleasesignat.releasesignaturecollectionenti
WHERE masterbatchrecordreleasesignat.releasesignaturecollectionenti IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(releasableentitykey);

How do I go about scripting and structuring this?

"not working" isn't very helpful. You're missing a closing parenthesis on your last query. And if you're doing that in PL/SQL you need to select into something or use a cursor.

@AlexPoole apologies, bit out of my depth with this so I'm not clear on why it's not working. When I provide a number directly for the WHERE clause the join works, when trying to use the array it fails. Good spot on the parenthesis, totally missed that - how would the select into work?

Why do you want to have the intermediate array at all - why can't you just do this with simple joins? A [mcve] might help explain things, as we can't see your tables or data or why you nee this construct.

One of the main problems with your code is that releasableentitykey is both the name of your PL/SQL variable and the name of a column in the masterbatchrecordreleasesignat which confuses the SQL engine as it will try to use the local SQL column in preference to the PL/SQL variable from the outer scope. ALWAYS name your PL/SQL variables with a different name to the columns.

You don't need a collection and can use the first query in the second query:
SELECT *
FROM   signature s
       INNER JOIN releasesignature rs
       ON s.entitykey = rs.signatureentitykey
       INNER JOIN masterbatchrecordreleasesignat mbrrs
       ON rs.entitykey = mbrrs.releasesignaturecollectionenti
WHERE  mbrrs.releasesignaturecollectionenti IN (
         SELECT releasesignaturecollectionenti
         FROM   masterbatchrecordreleasesignat mbrrs
                INNER JOIN masterbatchrecord mbr
                ON mbrrs.releasableentitykey = mbr.entitykey
         WHERE  mbr.entitykey = '7884867406'
       );

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE signature (entitykey) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE releasesignature (signatureentitykey, entitykey) AS
SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE masterbatchrecordreleasesignat (
  releasesignaturecollectionenti, releasableentitykey
) AS
SELECT 2, '7884867406' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '7884867406' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE masterbatchrecord (entitykey) AS
SELECT '7884867406' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ENTITYKEY
SIGNATUREENTITYKEY
ENTITYKEY
RELEASESIGNATURECOLLECTIONENTI
RELEASABLEENTITYKEY




1
1
2
2
7884867406


1
1
3
3
7884867406



If you did want to use a collection and PL/SQL:
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE number_list IS TABLE OF number;

Then:
DECLARE
  v_releasableentitykey  number_list;
  v_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  SELECT releasesignaturecollectionenti
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_releasableentitykey
  FROM   masterbatchrecordreleasesignat mbrrs
         INNER JOIN masterbatchrecord mbr
         ON mbrrs.releasableentitykey = mbr.entitykey
  WHERE  mbr.entitykey = '7884867406';

  FOR r IN (
    SELECT s.entitykey AS s_entitykey,
           rs.entitykey AS rs_entitykey
    FROM   signature s
           INNER JOIN releasesignature rs
           ON s.entitykey = rs.signatureentitykey
           INNER JOIN masterbatchrecordreleasesignat mbrrs
           ON rs.entitykey = mbrrs.releasesignaturecollectionenti
    WHERE  mbrrs.releasesignaturecollectionenti MEMBER OF v_releasableentitykey
  )
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.s_entitykey || ', ' || r.rs_entitykey);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Which outputs:
1, 2
1, 3

fiddle

Oh man, ashamed I didn't come to the first solution! I owe you a beer, both work perfectly.
Thanks!
